# Sending email via MailChimp with 2 different "from" emails causes vastly different stats

Tags: bulk-email, mailchimp, mail, dkim, dmarc

I have two domains:

- `abc.example`
- `xyz.example`

Both have the same DMARC and DKIM DNS records (relative to their own domain), both have same scores when checking black lists, mail tests sites etc

However, when I send from `example@abc.example`, MailChimp shows maybe 1,000 out of office emails bouncing back and an open rate of 10%. Using `example@xyz.example`, I get 10,000 out of office emails and an open rate of 40%. The exact same email. I've replicated this a few times now.

I have logged a ticket with MailChimp to see if they can offer any insight into what's happening but was wondering was there anything specific I could look into my side.

The only difference between the two domains is that `abc.example` is using DNS settings using the same provider that the hosting is with whereas `xyz.example` is using CloudFlare

Thanks

Comment: Are both of these email addresses new, or have one or both of them been sending email for a while?

Comment: They have both been around for several years